# PHP $_POST not being recognized

Tags: php

Just recently picked up PHP for a project, currently I'm trying to get PHP to recognize when the submit button has been hit and to print "Success" using the code below (Ignore the fetchIntervals() that calls a javascript function):

```
<button class = "button" type = "submit" name = "submit" onclick = "fetchIntervals()" method = "POST">Submit</button>
    <?php
        echo("Test"); //Prints out successfully 
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){ 
            echo("Post"); //Does not print
            if(isset($_GET["submit"])){
                echo("Success");
            }
        }
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET"){
            echo("Get"); //Prints successfully even though I'm using POST method
            if(isset($_GET["submit"])){
                echo("Success"); //doesn't print at all when button is pressed
            }
        }
    ?>
```

As said in the code I know it's entering into the PHP block since "Test" successfully prints out, but even though I'm using method = "POST" for my button the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET" is returning true and it's not even registering the button being clicked.

Comment: `method="POST"` goes in the `<form>` element, not `<button>`

Comment: Can you try to test by removing the onclick part? It's likely that `fetchIntervals()` contains some code that prevents the POST from happening. Also you probably need a `<form>` which should contain the `action`, the `method="POST"` and the submit button

Comment: You know that the PHP code runs on the server side, don't you? It can't react directly to a button click; the browser has to send a POST request and reload the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your code if the `button` element is wrapped inside a `form` element.
If it is not, the button should not be doing anything (i.e. it doesn't start a request to the server).
If it is, and the form has not got an attribute `method="POST"`, it will send the form with the GET method (by default). If you want to set the method in the `button` element, the attribute name is `formmethod` and not `method` [(Button specs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-formmethod).

When you first load the page, you are sending a `GET` request to the server. That is why the `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET")` test is true and the `echo("Get");` is executed.

A possible modification could be adding a `form` tag as a parent of the `button` element and set its attribute `method="POST"`. Setting the method on the button itself is usually not necessary, unless you have more submit buttons.

---

As a side note, `echo` is a language construct and not a function. Although it is allowed to call it with parenthesis, it is (wide) common practice to use it without.
Example: `echo "Get";`.

Comment: Thank you I hadn't put the button in a form, and preciate the tip on echo I'll be sure to implement that.